# ThreadID is not printed in log4j logs

Tags: multithreading, maven, selenium-webdriver, log4j, testng

I am executing a testng.xml from maven pom.xml with threadcount=5 specified in testng.xml. For debugging purpose I need to print threadID in the logs but not able to do that. Below are config details :-

```
Pom.xml
-------
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>

Testng.xml
----------

<suite name="Functionality Test" parallel="tests"
    verbose="5" thread-count="5" configfailurepolicy="continue" >
    <test name="Industry Brief" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.firstrain.XX" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="FR Labs">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.firstrain.YY" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

Log4j.properties pattern Layout
-------------------------------
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

Current Output
-------------
INFO [TestNG] (XX.java:27) - testme XX
INFO [TestNG] (YY.java:25) - testme YY
INFO [TestNG] (YY.java:26) - 1234
INFO [TestNG] (XX.java:27) - testme XX again
INFO [TestNG] (YY.java:47) - testme YY again

Expected Output
-------------
 INFO [pool-1-thread-1] (XX.java:27) - testme XX
 INFO [pool-1-thread-2] (YY.java:25) - testme YY
 INFO [pool-1-thread-2] (YY.java:26) - 1234
 INFO [pool-1-thread-1] (XX.java:27) - testme XX again
 INFO [pool-1-thread-2] (YY.java:47) - testme YY again
```

Comment: Can you post your test code? That output looks like your test code is possibly executing in a single thread. I'm assuming your test code must be doing a Thread.setName() ?

Comment: Kharyam,
Thx for the reply. I am not using  Thread.setName() anywhere in my code...When I am running my code the testng is running 5 parallel threads for test mentioned.

Comment: I even faced the same issue ... it always shows TestNG and you will never be able to make out which thread is running, it might be because TestNg internally sets the name of each thread to 'TestNG'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line to distinguish your threads in parallel execution

```
Thread.currentThread().getId()
```

or you can set name of the thread using

```
Thread.currentThread().setName(name)
```

and retrieve it using

```
Thread.currentThread().getName()
```

Comment: Yes Rishi I used the above method to rename each threadname with test class name. Thanks..